# How to add two help contents in eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In my application I want to add two help contents. Currently I have only one contents in my help book. To add a new one I have declared another help plugin and Tried to add that in to product dependencies. But my second help did not appear in the help book. Am i missing something here?
2 contents snapshot:

[image]

I want to do something like this

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Toc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?NLS TYPE="org.eclipse.help.toc"?>

<toc label="XXX">
    <topic label="Main Topic"  href="html/maintopic.html"> 
        <topic label="Sub Topic" href="html/subtopic.html"/> 
    </topic>
    <topic label="Main Topic 2"/>
</toc>
```

Comment: What extension points are you using for the help and what to your TOC xml files look like?

Comment: @greg-449 Edited my question please help.I think there is nothing wrong with the help .Problem is at the same time 2 helps content are not coming at the same time but on removing of any one help plugin from the dependency then  other one is coming and viceversa

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Eclipse help plug-ins they just use:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.help.toc"> 
   <toc file="toc.xml" primary="true" />
</extension>
```

in each `plugin.xml`. The `toc.xml` is like yours.